# Truncate table in Oracle getting errors

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I got the problem is when I run following command in Oracle, I encounter the error.

```
Truncate table mytable;
```

**Errors:**

```
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
```

I found that, this mytable has relationship with other tables. That's why Truncate command cannot proceed anymore. How to delete data from myTable with the SQL scripts using Truncate command?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You have to swap the TRUNCATE statement to DELETE statements, slower and logged but that's the way to do it when constraints are in place.

```
DELETE mytablename;
```

Either that or you can find the foreign keys that are referencing the table in question and disable them temporarily.

```
select 'ALTER TABLE '||TABLE_NAME||' DISABLE CONSTRAINT '||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
from user_constraints
where R_CONSTRAINT_NAME='<pk-of-table>';
```

*Where `pk-of-table` is the name of the primary key of the table being truncated*

Run the output of the above query.  When this has been done, remember to enable them again, just change `DISABLE CONSTRAINT` into `ENABLE CONSTRAINT`

Comment: I cannot use Delete statements because this table has over one million records and it would be getting slow if I use delete.

Comment: If it has 1 million records, I assume you are removing all the child records that are linked to it before doing the truncate?

Comment: I would follow cyberkiwi's option on disabling the constraints. This way you're not dropping constraints. Take a look at this article going more into detail about the behavior of truncate http://psoug.org/reference/truncate.html

Comment: eeesh ... getting late for me.  if possible truncate the tables that have foreign key references into this table if you are truncating all tables in your model.

Answer (score 14):

this page offers a very good solution ...

[ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys](http://snisaac.blogspot.com/2012/08/ora-02266-uniqueprimary-keys-in-table.html)

I'm here copying from it the Solution:

- Find the referenced ENABLED foreign key constraints and disable them.
- truncate/delete from the table .
- using any text editor .. just change disable to enable in the output you get from the query , then run it.

  ```
  select 'alter table '||a.owner||'.'||a.table_name||' disable constraint '||a.constraint_name||';'
  from all_constraints a, all_constraints b
  where a.constraint_type = 'R' and a.status='ENABLED'
  and a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
  and a.r_owner  = b.owner
  and b.table_name = upper('YOUR_TABLE');
  ```

Answer (score 8):

The error message is telling you that there are other table(s) with a foreign key constraint referring to your table.

According to the [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10007.htm#CHDDGIHF)

> You cannot truncate the parent table
>   of an enabled foreign key constraint.
>   You must disable the constraint before
>   truncating the table.

The [syntax for disabling a foreign key](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/disable.php) is:

> ALTER TABLE table_name disable
>   CONSTRAINT constraint_name;

Answer (score 5):

Issue:

```
Error “ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys” when trying to truncate a table.
```

Error Message:

```
SQL> truncate table TABLE_NAME;  

truncate table TABLE_NAME
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys
```

Solution:
-- Find the referenced foreign key constraints.

```
 SQL> select 'alter table '||a.owner||'.'||a.table_name||' disable constraint '||a.constraint_name||';'
  2  from all_constraints a, all_constraints b
  3  where a.constraint_type = 'R'
  4  and a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
  5  and a.r_owner  = b.owner
  6  and b.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';

    'ALTER TABLE'||A.OWNER||'.'||A.TABLE_NAME||'DISABLE CONSTRAINT'||A.CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_ATTACHMENT disable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;    
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_LOCATION disable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

-- Disable them

```
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_ATTACHMENT disable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_LOCATION disable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

-- Run the truncate

```
SQL> truncate table TABLE_NAME;

Table truncated.
```

-- Enable the foreign keys back

```
 SQL> select 'alter table '||a.owner||'.'||a.table_name||' enable constraint '||a.constraint_name||';'
  2  from all_constraints a, all_constraints b
  3  where a.constraint_type = 'R'
  4  and a.r_constraint_name = b.constraint_name
  5  and a.r_owner  = b.owner
  6  and b.table_name = 'TABLE_NAME';

'ALTER TABLE'||A.OWNER||'.'||A.TABLE_NAME||'ENABLE CONSTRAINT'||A.CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_ATTACHMENT enable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_LOCATION enable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

-- Enable them

```
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_ATTACHMENT enable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
alter table SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME_LOCATION enable constraint CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

Answer (score 4):

Oracle 12c [introduced a feature](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/truncate-table-cascade-12cr1) to truncate a table that is a parent of a referential integrity constraint having ON DELETE rule.

Instead of `truncate table tablename;` use:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename CASCADE;
```

From Oracle [`truncate table`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707) documentation:

> If you specify CASCADE, then Oracle Database truncates all child tables that reference table with an enabled ON DELETE CASCADE referential constraint. This is a recursive operation that will truncate all child tables, granchild tables, and so on, using the specified options.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach to delete many rows with many constraints is as follows:

- create `mytable_new` with all the columns but without constrains (or create constraints disabled);
- copy whatever data you need from `mytable` to `mytable_new`.
- enable constraints on `mytable_new` to see that everything is ok.
- alter any constraints that reference `mytable` to reference `mytable_new` instead and see that everything is ok.
- `drop table mytable`.
- `alter table mytable_new rename to mytable`.

It's far faster than deleting a million records with many slow constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue and I sorted it out by the following scripts.

```
begin
for i in (select constraint_name, table_name from user_constraints a where a.owner='OWNER' and a.table_name not in
(select b.table_name from user_constraints b where b.table_name like '%BIN%') 
  and  a.constraint_type not in 'P')
LOOP
  execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' disable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/

truncate table TABLE_1;
truncate table TABLE_2;


begin
for i in (select constraint_name, table_name from user_constraints a where a.owner='OWNER' and a.table_name not in
(select b.table_name from user_constraints b where b.table_name like '%BIN%') 
  and  a.constraint_type not in 'P')
LOOP
  execute immediate 'alter table '||i.table_name||' enable constraint '||i.constraint_name||'';
end loop;
end;
/
```

This script will first disable all the Constraints. Truncates the data in the tables and then enable the contraints.

Hope it helps.

cheers..

Answer (score 0):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE TEST2 DROP ALL STORAGE;
```

This statement Actually works when there is an foreign key constraint applied on a .table

Comment: This doesn't work for me unless the tables are already empty.  Can you create a reproducible test case?

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by the error message, you cannot truncate a table that is referenced by enabled foreign keys. If you really want to use the `truncate` DDL command, disable the foreign key constraint first, run the truncate command, and enable it back.

Reference: [Difference between TRUNCATE, DELETE and DROP commands](http://www.orafaq.com/faq/difference_between_truncate_delete_and_drop_commands#comment-6245)